# What is the enigmatic word?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> Well, it is always good to start slowly. Hence let us start slowly.
>   You are looking for a certain word in this paragraph which occurs
>   once only.  The first letter of this word is the seventh after a
>   vowel and this vowel is letter number seven to appear after its
>   last letter.  What is the enigmatic word?  What is it?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a puzzle. Is it any more complicated than "search the text for a word matching the description"/is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't understand this statement "this vowel is letter number seven to appear after its last letter"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just counting letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “enigmatic”

These types of puzzles usually tease like that. =)